# Setting the dimensions of a WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

i need to put a `WebView` with a specific size, 
like this :

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"        
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1" />
```

after that the `WebView` is loaded with an url image that I receive from a `JSON` object, my problem is that the image is larger than my specified dimensions mentioned earlier. As a result the `WebView` is not my desired size, to place the image I use:

```
    WebView wbb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings wbset=wbb.getSettings();
    wbset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());          
    wbb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbb.loadUrl(foto);
```

where `foto` is the url of an image, ex: [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i3LE.jpg)
I've tried with `scalexy` but that does not work either; any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `WebView` in a `Fragment` and have it fill the entire `Fragment`'s layout file;
Then add that `Fragment` to your `Activity`'s layout file contain a `Fragment` `View` with your specified dimensions.

This should resize your UI within the `Fragment`

Comment: yea just comment back on here if that doesn't fix it and we can try something else out!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```